# Apexcharts does not show data from web service

Tags: mysql, apexcharts

I am trying to integrate Apexcharts in my web app coded in core PHP without using any framework.

Here I want to retrieve data for the chart from a web service.

I am using JQuery also.

Here is HTML code:

```
<div id="bar-chart" class="apex-charts" data-colors="#6658dd"></div>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
var options = {
  chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'bar',
  },
  dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
  },
  series: [],
  title: {
      text: 'Date wise Consumption',
  },
  noData: {
    text: 'Loading...'
  }
}
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#bar-chart"), options);
chart.render();
$.getJSON(url, function(response) {
    chart.updateSeries([{
    name: 'Stock Usage',
    data: response
  }])
});
```

The code of web service is very simple. It is as follows:

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `sl_date`, `sl_qty` FROM `stock_levels` ORDER BY `sl_date`");
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql) )
{
   $response[] = array("date"=>$row['sl_date'],"value"=>$row['sl_qty']);
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

What mistake am I making here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Apexcharts accepts an array of [name, data] object for axis charts or [x, y] paired data or an array of values for non-axis (pie/donut) charts. (https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/series/). It doesn't accept JSON input so you would have to convert from JSON to arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But this sample on Apexchars says JSON is allowed: https://apexcharts.com/docs/update-charts-from-json-api-ajax/

If I add   var myJSON = JSON.stringify(response);   and then pass myJSON to data still it is not working. As I am creating a Bar chart it should handle two values.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way out.

I had to change one line in my web service from:

```
$response[] = array("date"=>$row['sl_date'],"value"=>$row['sl_qty']);
```

to

```
$response[] = array("x"=>$row['sl_date'],"y"=>$row['sl_qty']);
```

One thing that I am not able to achieve is: How to add multiple series to a Chart?

TIA